# How to format and mount an ebs volume to a running instance after attaching to it programatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using aws jdk to create and attach ebs volume to my running instance.
To make it available for use, I need to format and mount it on my instance.
Can not find support in aws jdk api for it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The aws jdk won't help you there.  The jdk only interact with AWS api that allow you to interact with the part of the infrastructure managed by Amazon.

The operation inside you instance is out of the responsibility of Amazon (they make sure they can't do it), so you need to do it you self.

You will need to run some process on your machine in order the new drive to have a valid file system and being mounted.

The way to do it will really depend on the OS you are using.

For Linux as you want the operation to work when the drive is added at run time, I will first try a cron job that list the available block device (by convention the EBS start for /dev/sbf [actual name depend on the Linux flavor]) compare it to the mounted one.  If a non mounted is found the scrip simply create the file system and then update fstab file.  Finally it calls `mount -a` to make sure every thing is correctly mounted.

There is probably some even system to trigger the script when the block device is added, but I will keep the expected state driven approach so you can still run it periodically and make sure transient issue are eventually fixed.